# MPZ conversion from hexadecimal to number

Tags: c++, hex

This is my first time using mpz. and I am trying to convert from a file a base 16 into x. For instance I want to convert 924e6c52cd7f03abcc5e into a number. But I am getting an error like such: gen_key.cpp(.text+0x29): undefined reference to '__gmpz_init'   for all the times I try to use gmpz. I included my code below, and appreciate any help.

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include "gmp.h"
#include "gmpxx.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#define CHUNK 10 //for remainder

//for now won't worry about command line but should come back later and do that !!!
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("cipher_text", "rt");   
mpz_t x;

mpz_init(x); 



    mpz_inp_str(x, fp, 16);   
    mpz_out_str(stdout,10,x);
 mpz_clear(x);   



return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've included the .h file, but have you also linked either to it's library or to the object file you got when building it's .cpp file too?

Comment: I do not know what you mean? What would i have to do when building the cpp?

Comment: If you're using an ide, you need to add the library in the linking options (either .a or .lib, depending on your compiler - .a for gcc, .lib for msvc/tc). If a library isn't included and you just get .cpp/.h files, then you need to add the .cpp files to your project like the main.cpp file is. Google searches for "build a program with multiple .cpp files" or "how do I link a library .cpp" will turn up results that will include something suitable for you. :)